# Simple custom formatting using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, scala

i want a very simple format to parse using datatimeformatter for the following:

1 1 1976 this is in d M yyyy format

What works:

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("d M yyyy")
format.parse("1 1 1976")
```

but

```
val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d M yyyy")
LocalDateTime.parse("1 1 1976", format)
```

throws

```
'1 1 1976' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 1976-01-01 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

not sure what is the best way to use Java 8 time in my case

Comment: For future reference, before posting here please do a Google search on the error message.  The first result for `"Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor"` was the existing SO post that answers your question.  Also, StackOverflow's search functionality is _abysmal_, and since Google does such a good job of indexing SO, there's no pressure on the SO developers to improve search or duplicate location :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LocalDate` instead of `LocalDateTime` solve your issue.

```
val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d M yyyy");
val date = LocalDate.parse("1 1 1976", format);
System.out.println(date);
```